# controlling what user sendmail runs scripts in aliases

Tags: sendmail, procmail

Suppose I have a line like this in my `/etc/aliases`:

> foo-bar: "|/etc/smrsh/some_script"

`some_script` is being run as user `mail`, but I need it to be running as user `nobody`.

I'm using `procmail` as the local delivery agent, and the system is some bastardized RHEL.

How can I configure sendmail or procmail to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with sudo and another script.  In /etc/sudoers, allow user mail to run commands as user nobody (and only user nobody) without a password, something like this:

```
mail  ALL = (nobody) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/script2
```

then the contents of some_script will be a wrapper for script2:

```
sudo -u nobody /usr/bin/script2
```

script2 will then execute as user nobody.

Note I make no guarantees that there aren't huge security holes in this.